# Bash Heredoc doesn't seem to work with Docker RUN statement

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to use Valve's `steamcmd` package in a bash script, an interactive shell that takes user input. Of course i'd like to be able to send input manually as part of a docker build, but I'm running into some issues.

I started by installing `steamcmd` locally and running this script:

```sh
./steamcmd <<LOGIN
login anonymous
quit
LOGIN
```

Unsurprisingly, it works properly, yielding this output:

```
Steam Console Client (c) Valve Corporation
-- type 'quit' to exit --
Loading Steam API...OK.

Connecting anonymously to Steam Public...Logged in OK
Waiting for user info...OK
Steam>
```

The problems start when I try the same command in Docker:

```
RUN ./steamcmd <<LOGIN \
login anonymous \
quit \
LOGIN
```

During the build, it runs `./steamcmd` but then hangs on the input prompt, none of the data in the Heredoc is passed and the build never completes. What am I doing wrong?

Extra Info:

- Base Image: `ubuntu:latest`
- User: non root

Comment: maybe it should be the `CMD` and not the `RUN`?

Comment: @EfratLevitan same result occurs

Comment: `RUN bash -c 'echo -e "login anonymous\nquit\n" | ./steamcmd'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker build process is completely non-interactive, and if you are looking for some input then you need to pass [build-args](https://vsupalov.com/docker-env-vars/), and the reference these build-args in your sub-sequent RUN command.

But as mentioned in the commend you need to run them as a `CMD` as it will stuck the build process.

Here is [Dockerfile](https://github.com/respawner/docker-steamcmd) with [some example](https://github.com/respawner/docker-steamcmd/tree/master/scripts) entrypoint that may help you,

```
# start steamcmd to force it to update itself
RUN ./steamcmd/steamcmd.sh +quit

# start the server main script
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/home/steam/server_scripts/server.sh"]
```

You can change it to

```
/home/steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh \
    +login anonymous \
    +exit
```

and one example from above list is  `cs_go.sh` which you need to rename to `server.sh` is

```
#!/bin/bash

# update server's data
/home/steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh \
    +login anonymous \
    +force_install_dir /home/steam/server_data \
    +app_update 740 \
    +exit

# start the server
/home/steam/server_data/srcds_run \
    -game csgo -console -usercon \
    -secure -autoupdate -tickrate 64 +hostport 27015 \
    +game_type 0 +game_mode 1 +mapgroup mg_active +map de_dust2 \
    -port 27015 -console -secure -nohltv +sv_pure 0 +ip 0.0.0.0

exit 0
```

**updated:**

**Automating SteamCMD**

There are two ways to automate SteamCMD. (Replace steamcmd with `./steamcmd.sh` on Linux/OS X.)

**Command line**

**Note:**   When using the -beta option on the command line, it must be quoted in a special way, such as `+app_update` "90 -beta beta".

**Note:**   If this does not work, try putting it like `"+app_update 90 -beta beta"` instead.

Append the commands to the command line prefixed with plus characters, e.g.:

```
steamcmd +login anonymous +force_install_dir ../csgo_ds +app_update 740 +quit
```

[Automating SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for the help! If I could ask, what is the significance of the '+' operator in bash? I've never seen it used and I couldn't find much info online.

Comment: pls, check the updated answer. this is the syntax of streamCMD for automating.